# PWA app freezes during app switching on iOS 13.4

Tags: ios, safari, progressive-web-apps, freeze

I have some problem with my PWA app on iOS 13.4.1 (iPhone 8) during app switching - it freezes when I'm switching to some other app and then return to my PWA app. If I repeat this action (app switch & return) - PWA app unfreezes.

I've developed other PWA app some time ago and it was working fine until now. Maybe some iOS update broke PWA functionality?

Comment: For what it’s worth, I have the same issue with one of my PWAs. Was working fine until I upgraded from 13.3.x to 13.4.1.

Comment: I'm using 13.4.1. And this happened to me TOO. Not only mine, other PWA has the same problem. So I believe this should be a bug in system level.

Comment: After some more searching, I found this: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=211018

Comment: And this: https://twitter.com/kpk/status/1257057933835132928

Comment: Just had this exact issue on 13.4 - upgrade to 13.5.1 fixed this issue for me. 

Comment: Broken again on 13.6

Comment: I am facing issues with 13.6.1, sometimes working sometimes not.

Comment: iOS 13.7 - same here. Sometimes it's working properly sometimes not.

Answer (score 1):

According to my personal experience and information in [this post](https://firt.dev/ios-14#bugs), it is fixed on iOS14.

> Many bugs from previous versions where solved, such as: **The frozen PWA with a Service Worker after a suspension**

Comment: Has anyone encountered this on iOS / iPad OS 15? (or iOS / iPad OS 16)